# Retrieve key value from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve only the key value not the child value from Firebase. I want to retrieve only "Comp 232" and "comp 231" as show in figure.

- Subject Details

  - Comp 232

    - subject name: Database
    - Teacher name : teacher 1
  - comp 231

    - subject name : microporcessor
    - teacher name: teacher 2

(I want comp 232 and comp 231 to be retrieved)

Here is my code...but this doesn't work:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArrayList);
myDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
myListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

myDataBase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String Value = dataSnapshot.child("Subject Details").getKey();
            myArrayList.add(Value);
            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're reading from the wrong level in your database. You want to start listening on `/Subject Details` and then add each child to the list:

```
myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Subject Details");
myListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

myDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        String Value = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        myArrayList.add(Value);
        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ...
```